# Transparent background with non-transparent button

Tags: html, css

I have a caption area over an image with a semi-transparent background. Within the caption area there's a button. I want the button to be non-transparent, but not sure how to do this.

http://dailyspiro.com/index.html

```
    <div class="col-md-12 landing-container">
        <img src="images/pig.jpg" class="main-image" width="70%">
        <div class="uvp">
        <h1>Spread Compassion & Track Your Impact</h1>
        <button class="join-button">Join Now</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.uvp {
    background: rgb(66,51,51);
    opacity: .8;
    ...
}

.uvp h1 {
    color: #fff;
    ...
}

.join-button {
    background: rgb(48, 118, 213);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opacity will apply to the element with `.uvp` and all its children. Have you tried `background: rgba(66,51,51,0.8)` instead?

You also need to place the image behind the `.uvp` You could do it with `position: relative; z-index: -1;` for the image.

A better solution might be `background: url(images/pig.png) center center no-repeat`for `.container` but then you need to take care of the height of `.container` yourself and the background-size, with `background-size: contain`.

Comment: That sounds like it should work, but when I try it, the background disappears.

Comment: Updated the answer with another suggestion

Answer (score 1):

you need use the z-index to put the transparent area back and the non-transparent to front
eg:
`

```
background: rgb(66,51,51);
opacity: .8;
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
```

`

`background: rgb(48, 118, 213);
    //if you want couldn't no change this class"`

Answer (score 0):

just change

```
.uvp {
    background: rgb(66,51,51);
    opacity: .8;
    ...
}

.uvp h1 {
    color: #fff;
    ...
}

.join-button {
    background: rgb(48, 118, 213);
    ...
}
```

to

```
.uvp {
    background: rgba(66,51,51,.8);
    ...
}

.uvp h1 {
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    ...
}

.join-button {
    background: rgb(48, 118, 213);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Seems like that should work but just updated the site to this, and now there's no background